# Why I cannot see json data in table?

Tags: html, json, vue.js, html-table

I am trying to display json data in tree hierachy table with vue.js. Unfortunally I cannot see any data inside of the table. The path is correct, I have checked this by URL adress, the format as well. My goal is to create tree hierarchy table, with action button for removing layers. I would like to mention thath I am new in Vue.js framework, so this is not maybe the best option how to work with fetched data from json file.

**HTML:**

```
    <table>

      <thead>
        
        <tr>

          <th>Name</th>

          <th>Parent</th>

          <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>

      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">

          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>

          <td>{{ item.parent }}</td>

          <td>

            <button @click="toggleChildren(item)">Toggle Children</button>

          </td>

          <template v-if="item.childrenVisible">

            <tr v-for="child in item.children" :key="child.id">

              <td>{{ child.name }}</td>

              <td>{{ child.parent }}</td>

              <td>

                <button @click="toggleChildren(child)">Toggle Children</button>

              </td>

            </tr>

          </template>

        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
```

**Vue.js code**

```
  <script>

    fetch('data/vue-data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

            new Vue({

                el: '#app',

                data: {
                    items: data.items
                },
                methods: {
                    toggleChildren(item) {
                        item.childrenVisible = !item.childrenVisible;
                    },
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Dear Petr, You have get it wrong. you need to first initalize Vue instance, and in one of its components, Try to fetch data, and then put your data inside of this.items. 
I should say you have to read the vue docs, and then try to visualize a simple data table, and then go for the nested one. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I second reading the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application) to gain a base level knowledge of the framework before trying to use it.  I recommend when setting up a new app to use the scaffolding tool with `npm init vue@latest` which will automatically create a barebones Vue application that will immediately be able to run on its own

Comment: Thank you all to your answers. How I said, I am new in Vue.js. So I am doing what bad? In which part I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create your app in advance. also where is your `#app` container?

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- your table data -->
</div>
```

and for the js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  // data should return an object, not be an object
  data() {
    return {
      items: [] // default value, could also be null
    }
  },

  // called on initialization, read about lifecycle hooks
  mounted() {
    fetch('data/vue-data.json').then(response => { this.items = response.json() })
  },

  methods: {
    toggleChildren(item) {
      item.childrenVisible = !item.childrenVisible;
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: If you click on my post, you'll see that the `<div>` with the app id is included, it just didn't show up.... I've tweaked the `mounted()` method a bit like this `mounted: function() {
        axios.get('data/vue-data.json')
            .then(response => {
              this.items = response.data;
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
      },`